# Angular 10 - Convert FormControl array values to Strings separated with commas

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

### EDIT 1 :

I modify my question to clarify my need.

I have a `FormGroup` that contains `FormControl`.

Among these `FormControl`, there is one that receives an array values.

What I'm looking for is if there is a solution to make the `FormControl` that receives an array values instead receive values in a comma separated string value (without the brackets `[]` ).

#### What I get :  ( Array Values )

[image: Array Values]

#### What I want : ( String values separated with comma without `brackets[]` )

[image]

Link of the fork : [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values)

- Thank you in advance for your help

### **Original Question :**

I would like to convert the data received from a `FormArray` to Strings with commas.

I managed to do this in Console.log, but I don't know how to send the converted data to the `FormGroup`.

My TS file :

```js
  accessoire: string;
  this.demandeDevis = this.formBuilder.group({
    accessoires: new FormArray([]),
    accessoire: this.accessoire,
  });

  onCheckboxChange(event) {
    const checkAcs: FormArray = this.demandeDevis.get(
      'accessoires'
    ) as FormArray;
    
    if (event.target.checked) {
      checkAcs.push(new FormControl(event.target.value));
      console.log(checkAcs.value.toString());
      this.accessoire = checkAcs.value.toString();
    } else {
      let i: number = 0;
      checkAcs.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
        if (item.value == event.target.value) {
          checkAcs.removeAt(i);
              return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
  }
```

My `HTML` :

```html
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item p-3">
      Ventilateur cabine
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" value="Ventilateur cabine" class="primary"
          (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item p-3">
      Manoeuvre pompier
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="primary" value="Manoeuvre pompier"
          (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item p-3">
      Afficheur à tous les étages
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="primary" value="Afficheur à tous les étages"
         (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item p-3">
      Gong
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="primary" value="Gong"
          (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
          <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item p-3">
      Système de secours automatique
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" class="primary" value="Système de secours automatique"
           (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" />
        <span class="slider"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

When I follow these steps, I get `null` on " Accessoire " and array values on " Accessoires ".

What I'm looking for is to take the values chosen from a checkbox list and convert them to strings with commas. I don't want to send them in Arrays form.

Thank you in advance for your solutions.

**EDIT 1 :**

I used the first Option of **@akash** solution and it's working. I have just a little problem. When i get the values selected on an `input`, and I want to send it to a `formControl` ... I get the array form with brackets ... What I want is string form with commas. here's the link of my problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values

Comment: providing a minimal repro on stackblitz would let people help you out without just guessing what's the issue and you'd probably get a higher number of answers

Comment: Cant you simply do this with var string = array.join() ? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```html
<mat-select 
      [value]="toppings.value?toppings?.value.split(','):null" 
      (selectionChange)="toppings.setValue($event.value.join(','))"
       multiple>
...
</mat-select>
```

Remember a `FormControl` exist even you has no input. Well, you need rewrite all your code to received an string, some like [this forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values-zalmcc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)

Comment: **It's Working !** This is what I was looking for :) Thank you @Eliseo for your answer.

And **Thank you all for your help guys of this topic** :)

Answer (score 3):

**Update 2**:

To populate your form from db values, just initialize the control `toppings` like below (see [this fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values-wp3ruz?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.ts)) -

```js
toppingsValue: string = 'Extra cheese, Mushroom';
this.demandeDevis = this.formBuilder.group({
      toppings: [this.toppingsValue.split(',').map(a => a.trim())]
});
```

**Update 1**:

I think I misunderstood what you're trying to achieve. Please understand how angular [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) works. `FormGroup` has controls field which is what you pass as an object below. This object is a key-value where key is your control name (toppings) and value is your control (eg. FormControl, FormArray or FormGroup) -

```js
this.demandeDevis = this.formBuilder.group({
      toppings: this.toppings 
});
```

So when you do `this.demandeDevis.value`, you get the object with same keys (toppings) and values in the corresponding control. You can use below code to get the comma separated values for `toppings`. Not sure if this is what you're looking for because this is obvious (see [this fork](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values-pbgwdo?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.ts)) -

```js
validateForm(){
    const toppingsValue = this.demandeDevis.controls['toppings'].value;
    console.log(toppingsValue.toString()); 
}
```

**Original answer**:

If you are open to different ways for how you'd like your UI to look like, use `angular material`

**Option 1**:

Use `mat-select` component. With below example, you don't need to handle selection/deselection of options. Please see [this example on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yp6tkk?file=src/app/select-multiple-example.html) -

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div>
{{toppings.value}}
</div>
```

**Option 2**:

If you don't want to use dropdown, use `mat-selection-list`, see [this example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/dmbeaojmpnx?file=src/app/list-selection-example.html). Below example uses reference to `mat-selection-list` to get the list of selected options in the component -

```html
<mat-selection-list #shoes (selectionChange)=selectionChange()>
  <mat-list-option [value]="shoe" *ngFor="let shoe of typesOfShoes">
    {{shoe}}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
{{selectedValuesG}}
```

Comment: I used the first Option and it's working. I have just a little problem. When i get the values selected on an input, and I want to send it to a formControl ... I get the array form with brackets ... What I want is string form with commas. here's the link of my problem : https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values

Comment: **@Akash** Yes! this is what I want to do ( Your Updated answer ), but I want to push the separated comma values to the FormControl ['toppings'] to push all form values to database ... see link https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values-vpi4xv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

Thank you :)

Comment: **@Akash** I saw your new answer, but what I'm looking for is when I validate the form, I don't want to send an array in "toppings", but a separate string with commas from the choices I choose (like the method **join()** ) but I don't know how to get it into the code.

Here is the image link to better explain : https://i.imgur.com/pXr5flf.png

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: I don't know why you want a comma separated string? The `mat-select` expects an array and you have to pass an array. That's how it works. Unless you could explain a need for having a comma separated string? If you want to save it to db as a string, you can always convert it.

Comment: **@Akash**  My partner has a BackEnd built with Spring Boot and MySQL, when I send the form data to the database, everything works fine, except for the accessories field, which is in array form.

In the accessory field in the MySQL database, I get something like [java.lang.strxhYE &]. This is why I want to convert the array values to a string separated with comma values before sending it to the database :)

Comment: Another aproach is simply used a string separated by commas as value of the control. The only is indicate [value]="value.split(',') (selectionChange)=setValue($event.value.join(","). See my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values-axqbsz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts)

```js
 ngOnInit() {
  this.initDemandeDevis();
  this.toppings.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    this.demandeDevis.patchValue({
      toppingsToString: value.length > 0 ? value.join(",") : ""
    });
  });
 }

 initDemandeDevis() {
   this.demandeDevis = this.formBuilder.group({
     toppingsToString: "",
     accessoires: null
   });
 }
```

You will have to split it back up to populate the toppings array, but I am not sure if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution will be to use `Observable` and transform the data whenever required.

```js
// We define an Observable list of toppings
allToppings$: Observable<string[]> = of (['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato']);

// We define our FormGroup
demandeDevis: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  toppings: [[]]
});

// Lets assume an initial topping in the form of string. Since MatSelect returns array, we will convert this to array and assign it to toppings selected
initialToppings$: Observable<string> = of('Onion, Pepperoni, Tomato'); 
initialToppingListArray$: Observable<string[]> = this.initialToppings$.pipe(
  map(toppingList => toppingList.split(',')),
  tap(toppings => this.toppings.patchValue(toppings))
);

// Next we define toppings and toppingsValue to extract toppings and toppings as a string from the form group
get toppings(): FormControl {
  return this.demandeDevis.get('toppings') as FormControl
};

get toppingsValue(): string {
  return this.toppings.value.join(',')
}

// Finally I will combine allToppings$ and initialToppingListArray$ to use one async pipe in the HTML
v$ = forkJoin([this.allToppings$, this.initialToppingListArray$]).pipe(
  map(([allToppings]) => ({ allToppings}))
)
```

In the HTML

```html
<form [formGroup]="demandeDevis" *ngIf='v$ | async as v'>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select formControlName="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of v.allToppings" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<button (click)="validateForm()" >
  Validate (console.log) 
  </button>
</form>


TOPPINGS VALUE: {{ toppingsValue }}
```

Now you can access the list as a string separated by using `toppingsValue`

[See Sample on Stackblit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values-o8csgk)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.
I used your solution, but I still get the chosen values in array form and not in a comma separated string values :)

Here's the link of the fork : https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values-pdyd7k

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a custom control

[See Working Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-string-values-dvh14h)

**app-string-select.ts**

```js
import { Component, forwardRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-string-select",
  templateUrl: "./string-select.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./string-select.component.css"],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => StringSelectComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class StringSelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  value: string[] = [];
  allToppings$: Observable<string[]> = of([
    "Extra cheese",
    "Mushroom",
    "Onion",
    "Pepperoni",
    "Sausage",
    "Tomato"
  ]);
  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouched: any = () => {};
  constructor() {}
  writeValue(value: string): void {
    this.value = value.split(",");
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  emitChange() {
    this.onChange(this.value.join(","));
  }
}
```

**app-string-select.html**

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)='emitChange()' multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of allToppings$ | async" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**select-multiple-example.ts**

```js
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms';
import {Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import {tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

/** @title Select with multiple selection */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-multiple-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-multiple-example.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class SelectMultipleExample {

  demandeDevis: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({ toppings: ['']});

  initialToppings$: Observable<string> = of('Onion,Pepperoni,Tomato').pipe(
    tap(toppings => this.toppings.patchValue(toppings))
  )

  get toppings(): FormControl {
    return this.demandeDevis.get('toppings') as FormControl
  };

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  validateForm(){
    const valuesForm = this.toppings.value;
    console.log(valuesForm); 
  }
}
```

**select-multiple-example.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="demandeDevis" *ngIf="initialToppings$ | async">
<app-string-select formControlName='toppings'></app-string-select>

<div>
   <button (click)="validateForm()" >
    Validate
  </button>
</div>
</form>
```